# Click event of asp image-button inside gridview using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, mouseclick-event

i have a grid-view, which contains an asp image-button for deleting row, i want to get the click event of that image-button using jquery, i want to animate the row before that row is deleted from database, i dont know what could be the best code for that, I used the below code, but it does not seems working.

```
$("#dnn_BlogCommentManager1_grdBlogComments td :img").click(function () {
            alert($(this).find('td:eq(4) :input').val());
        });
```

************************* UPDATES ***********************
i have 2 image-button inside gridview, i want the click event of the delete button only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no psuedo selector like `:img`. You can use type selector `image`. Use `closest` to find the parent `tr` and then you can find the required `td` element inside the `tr`. Try this.

```
$("#dnn_BlogCommentManager1_grdBlogComments [type=image]").click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4) :input').val());
});
```

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML, then you will now what the jQuery selector should filter on.